# Host (A) record (DNS) updated with wrong IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I recently installed a new Domain Controller running Windows Server 2012 (called "srv3") in a domain with two existents DCs that are running Windows Server 2003 (called "srv1" and "srv2"). All roles (DHCP, AD and DNS) have been migrated to the new server and are operational.

The issue is that the A record for "svr1"

I have some network connection problems though, and found out that the host (A) record of "srv1" in the forward lookup zone takes the ip address of "srv3".

I should have :

```
srv3      Host (A)    xx.xxx.6.4
srv1      Host (A)   xx.xxx.6.1
```

But I have :

```
srv3      Host (A)    xx.xxx.6.4
srv1       Host (A)    xx.xxx.6.4
```

Today I demoted both "srv1" and "srv2", turned them off and deleted the A record for "srv1" but it is still being registered back in DNS and it points to srv3's IP address (which is odd). The owner of svr1's A record appears to be "svr3"

Why would "svr3" create a record for "svr1" (and tie it to svr3's IP address)?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

- The output for

  ```
  netdom computername srv3 /ENUMerate
  ```

  is

  ```
  All the names of the computer are :
  srv3.myDomain.local
  srv1.myDomain.local
  ```
- I don't find any reference for srv1 in the content of the netlogon.dns file.
- Procedures followed : After installing and setting Windows Server 2012 on a new server, I installed AD, DNS and DHCP roles using "Add roles and Features". Then I transferred FSMO roles. After setting the new DNS, I found out that client's IP configuration (using `ipconfig /all` was good (implying new DNS), but the output of `nslookup` was `Default Server: UnKnown`. I discovored that the client's group policy was setting "srv1" as DNS. After getting rid of this parameter, some of the clients were connecting well and other not.

**EDIT 26/09/2014 15:56 (UTC+2)**

I checked that "srv3" is the primary name by executing the command `netdom computername srv3 /ENUMerate:PRIMARY`.

"srv1" was listed within alternate names (`netdom computername srv3 /ENUMerate:ALTERNATENAMES`).

I executed the following command :

```
    netdom computername srv3 /remove:srv1
```

and now I'm waiting to see if "srv1" will be registered again.

Does someone know why "srv3" have taken the name of "srv1" in the first place ?

Comment: I don't understand. What's coming back? The A record for srv3 or the A record for srv1?

Comment: The A record for srv3 is fine. But the A record for srv1 is coming back with the IP address of srv3... I guess it is created by srv3 since it is the owner of the record ?

Comment: I don't know why srv3 would be registering an A record for srv1. Is srv1 turned off?

Comment: srv1 is turned off. That's why I'm thinking that the record is created by srv3. I guess there is an error of configuration somewhere who leads into this

Comment: Is it possible to identify who creates this record ? Maybe in DNS debug log ? Thanks for the reply btw

Comment: How did you demote srv1 and srv2?

Comment: Using dcpromo on each server. I though it could resolve the problem who existed before I demoted them.

Comment: What's the output of `netdom computername %computername% /ENUMerate`

Comment: Just for the heck of it check the contents of the netlogon.dns file on srv3 at `C:\Windows\System32\config` for any reference to srv1.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help. I'm not at work anymore so I will answer that in the morning. I will detail the procedures that I followed and try to give more informations, put some screenshots if it can help. And thanks for the edit of the original post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be resolved. I don't know why "srv3" took "srv1" as an alternate name in the first place, but that's why "srv1" was being registered in the forward lookup zone with "srv3"'s IP address.

I removed "srv1" from the alternates names of "srv3" with the command :

```
netdom computername srv3 /remove:srv1
```

Since "srv1" is not registered anymore.